# How can I stop loader's animation after 3 seconds

Tags: jquery, animation, tailwind-css

my web project has a loader. I can make this loader visible when the site is opened, but I want it to close after 3 seconds, but I could not find how to do this. Please help me :)
I am using tailwindcss as a css framework.
I am using Jquery as a Js framework.
HTML :

```
<div id="loader" class="w-full h-screen absolute z-50 flex justify-center items-center bg-black hidden">
    <div id="loading" class="w-32 h-32" style="background: url(/images/loader.jpg)no-repeat center center;background-size:cover;"></div>
</div>
<div class="w-full h-screen flex flex-col md:flex-row">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 h-full flex flex-col text-center justify-center gap-4 items-center bg-green-450">
        <p class="text-7xl font-bold" style="font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;">KATILIMCIYIM</p>
        <p class="text-5xl w-1/2 ">Geçici Personel Arıyorum</p>
        <button class="rounded-full shadow-2xl text-4xl px-6 py-2 focus:outline-none bg-yellow-450 hover:bg-yellow-500 mt-16" style="color:#1AA057;">BAŞVUR</button>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 h-full flex flex-col text-center justify-center gap-4 items-center bg-yellow-450">
        <p class="text-7xl font-bold" style="font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;">PERSONELİM</p>
        <p class="text-5xl w-1/2 ">Fuarda Çalışmak İstiyorum</p>
        <button class="rounded-full shadow-2xl text-4xl px-6 py-2 focus:outline-none bg-green-450 hover:bg-green-500 mt-16" style="color:#FBB13E;">BAŞVUR</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .bg-yellow-450 {
        --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
        background-color: rgba(251, 177, 62, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    }

    .bg-green-450 {
        --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
        background-color: rgba(26, 160, 87, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    }

    #loading {
        animation: load 1s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes load {
        0% {
            width: 8rem;
            height: 8rem;
        }

        50% {
            width: 9rem;
            height: 9rem;
        }

        100% {
            width: 8rem;
            height: 8rem;
        }
    }
```

JS

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "flex";
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JQuery, you can delay a call to a function by calling `delay()` and pass in milliseconds. Then to hide the item use `fadeOut()`, again pass in milliseconds for the length of the animation.

**For example:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "flex";
        $("#loader").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000)
 });
```

Note: the JQuery equivalent of `document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "flex";` is: `$("#loader").css('display', 'flex')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

do this in your JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "flex";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "none";
     },3000); // 3000ms = 3 seconds
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply :)